# How to redirect a command result from channel to another?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a discord bot and I made a "say" command.
I want to redirect the result of the command to a different channel. For example, I write the command `!say hey` in channel "A" but the message is sent in channel "B".

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return;
  const sayMessage = args.join(" ");
  message.delete().catch();
  message.channel.send(sayMessage);
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "say"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not used discord.js in a while but I believe it's because you're using the `.channel` property of the message you receive.
eg: The message is received on channel 1 so using its channel property will send it on channel 1.

What you want to do is get a reference to the channel you wish to send it to then use that channels `.send` method.

Something like below you will need to find the ID of the channel you wish to post to.

```
client.channels.get(theChannelID).send('My Message');
```